# Detect when mouse actually moves, not just when the page moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, mousemove

I'm having a pretty big problem trying to create navigation on my page. If the mouse enters an element then it selects it, then if you use arrow keys it will select the elements relative to the selected one. However this is an issue when the arrow keys cause the page to scroll, because (depending on the position of the mouse) it will select the appropriate element then instantly select the item the mouse is now over after the page moved (even if you didn't move the mouse).

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I tried tinkering with it but none of my solutions seemed to work. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you *want* the page to move or don't you?  Can you perhaps set up a fiddle that illustrates your problem?

Comment: I want it to move the page on key up and keydown, but it's the fact that when the page moves the mouse is now over a different item then it selects that item. So if the cursor is in the center of the page, and you use the arrow keys to navigate down the page, every time the page moves down it will select the item that is now in the center of the page, when it should be on the bottom. I'll look into setting up a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should bind the "select when mouse enters" event on `mousemove` and unbind said event on `mousestop`.  `mousestop` does not exist on its own, so you will have to create it somehow or use a plugin (there are at least a few out there such as https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-mousestop-event/ ).  I think this would be the simplest solution, but your UI seems a little bizarre (you want the arrow key to scroll the page normally *and* "select" an element that's possibly larger than the scroll size?)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand, but you should be able to use a combination of the `mousemove` and `keypress` events:

```
$("#element").mousemove(function(e){
    alert("mouse moved");
});

$("#element").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40){ //up & down arrow keys
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false from the keyboard event handler where you check for arrow keys:

```
element.onkeypress = function(ev) {
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

This will prevent the "default behavior" that the browser has for the event, which is to scroll. This works also for links, for example: if you return false from a `click` event handler for a link, clicking the link will not automatically follow it.

Comment: Nope, even with return false it continues to select the item where the cursor is.

Comment: Returning false is supposed to inhibit scrolling, not selecting the item where the cursor is.

Comment: I'm not trying to stop scrolling though... I'm trying to stop the cursor from selecting the item when you are navigating with arrow keys, rather than moving the mouse.